# Does Mysql support Ethiopian calendar/ Ethiopian date time

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any concept in mysql to localize the Date time function. I need Date time to be in Ethiopian format. Or atleast a mysql conversion function that displays datetime with respect to Ethiopian Date time.

Comment: is this about timezone, or datetime display format? Please be more specific and explain what you need.

Comment: I believe that the OP is asking for a MYSQL date format using the Ethiopian calendar. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethiopian_calendar

Comment: Schlies, Yes. Im asking for any date function available, that will show in Ethiopian date format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not. In MySQL, [proleptic Gregorian calendar](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-calendar.html) is used - and there are no other formats. That means there are no *native* ways to produce such conversions.

However, you can create your own output conversion. To do this, you will need to know both calendars. There are good [on-line convertors](http://www.gebeya.net/dateconverter.aspx) which you can use to get some examples. So you will store your dates in Gregorian (i.e. MySQL internal) format, but convert them in your application like you need.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not a conversion function for ethiopic calendar.

The most straightforward approach would be to create a date table that contains gregorian date on one column and ethiopian on the next, allowing you to easily join it on a standard date to get your ethiopian date.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't support Ethiopian calendar but you can convert Gregorian date to Ethiopic  by creating **mysql** function and also you can customize it for other database and other programming language.
This is the GitHub link  [click here](https://github.com/mameaplus/gregorianToEthiopic/blob/main/gregorianToEthiopic.sql)